# Images not printing after the latest security update

Tags: winapi, hbitmap, stretchblt

My application fails to print after [the latest security update](https://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-confirms-crashes-caused-latest-windows-10-update).

None of the API calls fail, yet the images don't show even in PDF. Text and shapes like lines print fine.

The code loads a JPG image using IPicture interface and OleLoadPicture(). Then I use its Render() call to convert it into a HBITMAP and finally StretchBlt() on printing HDC.

None of the calls fail, all return values are checked. Everyhing worked fine until today and latest Windows security updates. Sure, if I uninstall KB5000808 update on my computer or KB5000802 on my client's computer everything is back to normal but this is not a long term solution.

Anyone having similar problems as of today? Any idea how to solve this? Any other way to print images?

EDIT:

Same problem even if I use a bitmap instead of a JPG image. So there's no problem with JPG rendering. On the other hand, both JPG and BITMAP show on the screen. Only printing does not work.

Comment: Looks similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607946/calling-windows-selectobject-in-a-printer-compatible-device-context-returns-null). I traced the issue down to a call to `SelectObject`. Strangely, other applications continue printing bitmaps.

Comment: You write that non of the API calls fail. Are you verifying the return value of `SelectObject`?

Comment: SelectObject() looked so innocent that I hardly ever check its result. Well, sure yes, I get NULL. Amazingly, even if I create new HDC on my own - CreateDC ("DISPLAY", NULL/*prnName*/, NULL, NULL); - SelectObject() will fail again even on that HDC as well as if I have try with valid printer name obtained via GetDefaultPrinter().

Comment: Keep in mind that bitmaps can only be selected into a memory device context. You need to set `HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(prn);` and use that. I guess that will fail for the printer but succeed for the display.

Comment: This is what I had all this time: hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(prn); But since yesterday I tried everything, even creating a DC on my own with the printer name or with a text DISPLAY. None of it lets me add a bitmap to it with SelectObject() while printing. Outside of printig the same code works just fine. And actually I have one and only function for displaying bitmaps., on screen or on printer.

Comment: And I even used a hdc from a front window. So .... HDC winHdc = GetDC (frontHwnd);  HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC (winHdc);  HBITMAP hSavedBitmap = SelectObject (hdcMem, hBitmap); ... This code snippet works well while I'm drawing things on the screen, but when I start printing it fails on SelectObject(). Amazing.

Comment: There is another discussion of this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607946/calling-windows-selectobject-in-a-printer-compatible-device-context-returns-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by using StretchDIBits instead of StretchBlt win32 api

Comment: I directly use the win32 api. 
I have never used IPicture. But looking at documentation could you not simply call IPicture::Render with the printer DC?

Comment: I'd be happy to accept your answer as I'm investigating StretchDIBits() and GetDIBits() but can you please post a link or give some example code? A function having passed HBITMAP and HDC and drawing it with StretchDIBits()

Comment: IPicture and render into the printer dc? Good question. Maybe I can really do that. And I'm using IPicture from plain C so I call it as iPicture->lpvtbl->Render();

Comment: In the end I solved it by using Render from IPicture. Thanks for leading me to the simplest solution.

Comment: In my case, I was lucky enough to to be creating my hbitmap with the CreateDIBSection api. So I had all information required for call to StreDIBits.But you can look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606906/saving-bmp-file-using-hbitmap-createdibsection-in-c-win32

Obviously, you won't save file, but you will have all the information you need.
Also, be careful of ySrc parameter in StretchDIBits call , I needed to reverse it (height-y).

Comment: That's great news! Cheers!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. Seems like I had the bitmap code ready before I even realised how to handle IPicture and since BitBlt() lets me use transparency converting IPicture to a bitmap seemd like a good idea.