# Calling Windows SelectObject in a printer-compatible device context returns NULL

Tags: winapi, printing

A recent Windows 10 update (probably and also mysteriously [KB4577586](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4577586-update-for-the-removal-of-adobe-flash-player-october-27-2020-931521b9-075a-ce54-b9af-ff3d5da047d5)) seems to have had the effect of causing calls to [SelectObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject) with a bitmap handle as an argument to return NULL when performed in a printer-compatible device context.

The relevant lines can be seen in this [bitmap printing example](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/261009-bitmap-printing-tutorial-in-c-win32/), which works fine on earlier Windows 10 versions, and seems to have worked fine for the past ten years. You can find a full minimal working example in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/dspinellis/win32-bitmap-print).

```cpp
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,szFileName,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_CREATEDIBSECTION|LR_DEFAULTSIZE|LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_VGACOLOR);
// [...]
HDC prn = GetPrinterDC(hwnd);
hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(prn);
HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
// hbmOld is NULL at this point, indicating SelectObject failure
```

The problem stops occurring after [uninstalling Windows update KB5000802](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-uninstall-update-kb5000802-fix-blue-screen-problems-windows-10), but this is obviously not a long-term fix.

Comment: Looks like something similar to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66606632/images-not-printing-after-the-latest-security-update (Solved it by uninstalling the KB5000808/802)

Comment: @RemyLebeau According to the [SelectObject documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject) and [this detailed explanation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100416-00/?p=14313) SelectObject will return NULL only in an error case. In the example I posted it returns NULL after the Windows update and in that case nothing is printed.

Comment: And as a confirmation that SelectObject() is the only problem here, creating a HDC at startup from a hdc of a regular window, selecting a bitmap in it with SelectObject() and then using that memory DC later will eventually print the bitmap. Unfortunately, this is not a solution of any kind.

Comment: Hi,I can reproduce this issue now. And I will confirm it with Internal engineer, and response here if there is any update.Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT: thank you! This is a critical issue for us as customer reports are rolling in and there's no work-around other than not printing logos onto invoices or uninstalling KB5000808/802 resolves the problem.

Comment: According to this, Microsoft seems to have acknowledged the bug and is working on a fix.

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-warns-of-more-printing-issues-caused-by-march-updates/

Comment: [The hotfix is out](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/march-18-2021-kb5001649-os-builds-19041-870-and-19042-870-out-of-band-ebbe0617-3a63-467a-aaaa-2a4c68a6de33). "Updates an issue that fails to print the graphical content in a document after installing the March 9, 2021 update."