# KB5000808/KB5000802 causes bitmaps/text objects to render invisibly

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

We've been dealing with an issue in our software ever since Microsoft released KB5000802/808 in early March. I've seen a similar post about it here, and the code we use is virtually the same (and hasn't changed in many years):

[Calling Windows SelectObject in a printer-compatible device context returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607946/calling-windows-selectobject-in-a-printer-compatible-device-context-returns-null)

In our case, we are actually printing OK, but our objects (bitmaps and text boxes) render invisibly on the screen (only "resize handles" appear) until we de-select and re-select the object. Rolling back the security update is a workaround but it's becoming more difficult to do this. We also have tested with Microsoft's hotfix KB5001649, but the issue persists. Has anyone else encountered this?

'''

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,szFileName,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_CREATEDIBSECTION|LR_DEFAULTSIZE|LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_VGACOLOR);
// [...]
HDC prn = GetPrinterDC(hwnd);
hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(prn);
HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
// hbmOld is NULL at this point, indicating SelectObject failure
```

'''

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Be sure to read the notes in [`SelectObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject): *Bitmaps can only be selected into memory DC's. A single bitmap cannot be selected into more than one DC at the same time.*

Comment: And why are you using `LR_VGACOLOR`?  I have no idea what it does, the documentation about it is very sparse.  It might be creating a bitmap that's incompatible with your DC.

Comment: In the minimal example, it loads a bitmap from disk. We are not actually loading it from disk but we are drawing it ourselves. But the hBitmap is valid and if we save it to disk it is correct. We are only selecting it into a memory DC and it is not being selected into more than one DC at a time. We did double-check if there were any recent changes on our side but this code has been in place for over 10 years.

Comment: Unfortunately it's possible for out-of-spec code to be working for years until an update causes the specs to be more strictly applied.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't determine which update patch caused the problem, but it seems to be related to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/382852/enhanced-metafile-emf-rendering-regression-during.html?childToView=383109#comment-383109) thread, maybe you updated an additional patch that caused the problem.

Comment: @dspinellis I wasn't able to comment on your original thread but are you able to confirm that the Microsoft fix worked for you?

Comment: Yes, after I updated the KB5001649 patch, I was able to solve the problem of the original thread.